# Fitting mixture of beta distributions with flexmix in R

Tags: r, statistics

Given the data (one-dimensional, non-repeated observations between 0 and 1), fit the model of one uniform (which is just fixed beta) and k beta distributions with varying k.

After trying many approaches (my own EM implementation as well), I turned to `flexmix` package on CRAN. However, it seems there is no inbuilt family for Beta distributions (like for Poisson, Binomial and Gamma). However there is an option to write an M-step for an arbitrary mixture.

Given the example M-driver in the vignette, `mymclust` I just got horribly entangled with the objects and dependencies and do not even know where to start.

How do I write this driver for my task?

Comment: Have you see Achim Zeileis' answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/115338/8141)?